# kotlin interface member's default visibility

Tags: kotlin

I am learning kotlin.

We can put properties or functions into kotlin interface. However, what's their default visibility? Are they open or abstract?

In the book kotlin in action, it says:

> A member in an interface is always open; you can’t declare it as final.
> It’s abstract if it has no body, but the keyword isn’t required.

What does body mean? In terms of function, does it mean function body? In terms of property, what does body mean? Property has the following full syntax, but which part is the body of property? getter/setter function can have body too, don't they?

```
var <propertyName>[: <PropertyType>] [= <property_initializer>]
    [<getter>]
    [<setter>]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The body is anything beyond the signature.

For a property, the signature is the name, and the type. For a function, it is the name, parameters, and return type.

The getter and setter of a property are its body. Adding a property initializer to a property gives it an implicit getter and setter, so the initializer can be thought of as part of the body. But you can't use initializers in interfaces.

For a function, the body is anything within the brackets after the return type (or for a [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions), whatever is after the `=`).

Basically, in an interface, if you put nothing after the type or return type, then it is abstract. Abstract means it has no implementation defined.

Properties and functions in interfaces are always open. You cannot make them final in the interface (but you can in the subclasses that implement them).

Answer (score 0):

Default visibility in Kotlin is `public`. Regarding open and abstract, I think quoted text described it well - they are always open and if you don't provide a body, they're automatically abstract. In the case of functions body means function body. In the case of properties it means body of either getter or setter. I believe it is not possible to implement a getter and leave a setter abstract or vice versa, so in practice it doesn't matter if we talk about a property, getter or setter - they can only be all at once abstract or not.